# responsive width of (float left) div according to distance to adjacent (float right) div

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, positioning

I am trying to use text ellipsis on a (float left) div which is 'sandwiched' between a (float left) div and a (float right) div.

[float left][float left (needs width for elipsis)]      [float right]

My problem is that to use text ellipsis I need to specify width or max-width of the 'sandwiched' div. But I do not know how to do this, because that width depends on the distance to the adjacent (float right) div, which depends on browser window width.

Please check the codepen below. If you shrink the browser window's width you will see that the info icon jumps to next line when colliding with the text I need to ellide.

To put it simply, I would like both L/R arrows and info icon to stay leftmost and rightmos respectively, no matter window width, and the text in the middle to elide according to window width.

I searched and I see I could do this with calc, but I am looking for a not so experimental solution.

Thank you very much.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLMBMJ

here is HTML code

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="subie">

    <div id="control">
        <button id="prv" class="button">←</button>
        <button id="pos" class="button">→</button>
      </div>

      <div id="title">
        <span id="page">Gloria Anzaldúa- Borderlands, La Frontera, The New Mestiza</span>
      </div>

      <div id="info">
        <button id="" class="button"><img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/32/info.png" width="33px"></button>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 5.5vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 100;
}

#subie {
  position: absolute;
  left: 51vw;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 5.5vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0vh 1vw 0vh 1vw;
}

#control {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5.5vh;
}

#title {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5.5vh;
  width: ;
}

#info {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5.5vh;
}

.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```